# Django with filtered join

Tags: django

I have an inner join:

```
SELECT c.name, b.name FROM company c
INNER JOIN branch b ON b.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 5 AND b.employees > 10;
```

That I got 3 registers.

How do I make this query in Django to returns only 3 registers?

```
c = Company.objects.prefetch_related("comp_branches").filter(id=5, comp_branches__employees__gt=10)
c[0].comp_branches.all()  # returns 5 registers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

c = Company.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('comp_branches', Branch.objects.filter(employees__gte=10))
).filter(id=5)
```

Here *`Brach`* is the model that is targeted by `comp_branches`, this thus might be different.

If you `.filter()`, you do not filter on the related objects you are prefetching, since that is done in a separate query. The `comp_brances__employees__gte=10` would only remove `Company`s from the `QuerySet` that have no brach with 10 or more employees.